# mongorestore doesn't skip errors without /stopOnError flag

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I use mongo 2.6.4 / Windows Server 2012 R2.

Mongodump generated two dump files:
`mongodump -d mydb`

- transaction.bson
- transaction.metadata.json

I tried to restore this information by mongorestore (2.6.4):

`mongorestore --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27018 --collection transaction --db mydb`

But tool return error (progress ~23%):

`2015-08-17T19:45:51.844+0400    Failed: restore error: mydb.transaction: error restoring from F:\restore\transaction.bson: insertion error: Client Error: bad object in message: invalid bson type in object with _id: ObjectId('528dc7c03599b01214d17469')`

So I decided to extend it by flags:

`mongorestore --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27018 --collection transaction --db mydb --drop --noIndexRestore --noOptionsRestore --noobjcheck --filter "{'_id' : { $ne: '528dc7c03599b01214d17469' }}" F:/restore/transaction.bson`

And got the same error again.

So I tried to use mongorestore from 3.0 version:

`mongorestore /host 127.0.0.1 /port 27018 /collection transaction /db mydb /drop /noIndexRestore /noOptionsRestore /keepIndexVersion F:/restore/transaction.bson`

And got the same error again.

I was hoping it helps because I didn't use /stopOnError flag. But it's not.
All the time it fails at ~23%.

Here is part of MongoDB log:

`2015-08-17T19:14:32.447+0400 [conn8] Assertion: 10307:Client Error: bad object in message: invalid bson type in object with _id: ObjectId('528dc7c03599b01214d17469')
2015-08-17T19:14:32.532+0400 [conn6] insert mydb.transaction ninserted:10000 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) w:181893 181ms
2015-08-17T19:14:32.743+0400 [conn9] insert mydb.transaction ninserted:10000 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) w:211264 211ms
2015-08-17T19:14:32.921+0400 [conn7] insert mydb.transaction ninserted:10000 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) w:176525 177ms
2015-08-17T19:14:36.250+0400 [conn8] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\stacktrace.cpp(169)                           mongo::printStackTrace+0x43
2015-08-17T19:14:36.250+0400 [conn8] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\log.cpp(127)                                  mongo::logContext+0x9c
2015-08-17T19:14:36.250+0400 [conn8] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\assert_util.cpp(183)                          mongo::msgasserted+0xfb
2015-08-17T19:14:36.250+0400 [conn8] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\assert_util.cpp(174)                          mongo::msgasserted+0x13
2015-08-17T19:14:36.250+0400 [conn8] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\dbmessage.cpp(116)                              mongo::DbMessage::nextJsObj+0x11f
2015-08-17T19:14:36.250+0400 [conn8] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\instance.cpp(898)                               mongo::receivedInsert+0x18f
2015-08-17T19:14:36.250+0400 [conn8] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\instance.cpp(484)                               mongo::assembleResponse+0x7c9
2015-08-17T19:14:36.250+0400 [conn8] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\db.cpp(202)                                     mongo::MyMessageHandler::process+0x111
2015-08-17T19:14:36.250+0400 [conn8] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\net\message_server_port.cpp(210)              mongo::PortMessageServer::handleIncomingMsg+0x671
2015-08-17T19:14:36.250+0400 [conn8] mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\boost\libs\thread\src\win32\thread.cpp(185)  boost::'anonymous namespace'::thread_start_function+0x21
2015-08-17T19:14:36.250+0400 [conn8] mongod.exe    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\threadex.c(314)      _callthreadstartex+0x17
2015-08-17T19:14:36.250+0400 [conn8] mongod.exe    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\threadex.c(292)      _threadstartex+0x7f
2015-08-17T19:14:36.250+0400 [conn8] KERNEL32.DLL                                                                   BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
2015-08-17T19:14:36.250+0400 [conn8] 
2015-08-17T19:14:36.255+0400 [conn8] insert mydb.transaction keyUpdates:0 exception: Client Error: bad object in message: invalid bson type in object with _id: ObjectId('528dc7c03599b01214d17469') code:10307 numYields:0  0ms`

I want to read data from this file, but it's huge (18 Gb).
It's okay if some records will be skipped.

Anybody knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`mongodump` is good to dump the whole db. If you just want to work with one collection, try to export the `transaction` collection with `mongoexport` like `mongoexport --collection transaction --db mydb --out transaction.json` and import it with `mongoimport --collection transaction --db mydb --file transaction.json`.
If you are restoring a full dump and it fails with a certain collection then you can do the restore without the offending collection by using the following flag `--excludeCollection transaction`

Comment: I dump whole and have the same like @kipwoker. I have always some problems with MongoDB restore, never easy.